# CoreData only shows one data

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

This is my Model:

```
struct dataALLDoc : Codable {
    let status : Bool
    let code : Int
    let message : String
    let body : [BodyALLDoc]
}
struct BodyALLDoc : Codable  , Hashable{
    var  vehicleDescription : String?
    var  model : String?
    var  identifier : String?
    var  ownership : String?
    var  personInCharge : String?
    var documents : [aLLDocumento]
    var _id : String?
}
struct aLLDocumento : Codable , Hashable {
    var document : String?
    let expiredIn : String?
    let description : String?
    let documentType : String?
    let lastUpdated : String?
    let _id : String?
}
```

BodyALLDoc contains only one vehicle while aLLDocumento contains several documents, this is my call to my api together with my saving in coredata

```
func GetALLDataDocumento(context : NSManagedObjectContext){
        let url = "http://api/allVehicles"
              var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
              request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
                  "Authorization": "xxx"
              ]

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, error) in
            guard let jsonData = data else { return }
            let response = res as! HTTPURLResponse
            if response.statusCode == 404 {
                print("FAIL")
                return print("") }
            do {
                let dataInfo = try decoder.decode(dataALLDoc.self, from: jsonData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.ALLINFO = dataInfo
                    self.saveDataALL(context: context)
                }
            } catch { print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)") }
        }.resume()
    }
//GetALLDataDocumento give me the all of my documents

func saveDataALL(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        ALLINFO?.body.forEach { data in
            data.documents.forEach { document in
                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<AllData> = AllData.fetchRequest()
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifierALL == %@", data.identifier!)
                do {
                    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    if let existingEntity = results.first {
                        existingEntity.vehicleDescriptionALL = data.vehicleDescription ?? ""
                        existingEntity.personInCharge = data.personInCharge ?? ""
                        existingEntity.ownershipALL = data.ownership ?? ""
                        existingEntity.modelALL = data.model ?? ""
                        existingEntity.lastUpdatedALL = document.lastUpdated ?? ""
                        existingEntity.expiredInALL = document.expiredIn ?? ""
                        existingEntity.documentTypeALL = document.documentType ?? ""
                        existingEntity.docindocumentosALL = document.document ?? ""
                        existingEntity.descriptionDOCALL = document.description ?? ""
                    } else {
                        let newEntity = AllData(context: context)
                        newEntity.identifierALL = data.identifier ?? ""
                        newEntity.vehicleDescriptionALL = data.vehicleDescription ?? ""
                        newEntity.personInCharge = data.personInCharge ?? ""
                        newEntity.ownershipALL = data.ownership ?? ""
                        newEntity.modelALL = data.model ?? ""
                        newEntity.lastUpdatedALL = document.lastUpdated ?? ""
                        newEntity.expiredInALL = document.expiredIn ?? ""
                        newEntity.documentTypeALL = document.documentType ?? ""
                        newEntity.docindocumentosALL = document.document ?? ""
                        newEntity.descriptionDOCALL = document.description ?? ""
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving data: \(error)")
        }
    }

//when i try to print one of the data saved in core data from documents, only prints 1 document
```

My problem is that when I bring all my data,  I want to access to the documents in my coredata it only brings me the first document and not all the ones that should be.

My view :

```
@FetchRequest(entity: AllData.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \AllData.identifierALL, ascending: true)])
    var ALLResults: FetchedResults<AllData>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context


 List(ALLResults){ v in
 NavigationLink {
 ScrollView {
Text( "TIPE: " + (v.documentTypeALL ?? " "))
                                 .font(.title2)
}
}label: {
     Text( v.identifierALL!)
         .font(.title2)
}.onAppear(perform: {
                    jsonModelo.GetALLDataDocumento(context: context)
                })
```

And this is my coredata entitie

I tried to modify my function "saveDataALL" several times but it has not given me any result
what I expect is that in my coredata it brings me all the data that I have in my struct aLLDocumento.
Im sorry if my english is not good :(

Comment: Have you verified that all data is saved in saveDataAll?

Comment: In saveDataAll when i print the data, prints all of my vehicles, but prints only the first document of my vehicles

Comment: Now I see what you’re doing, you have only one entity but you use it to store 2 types that had a one to many (an array) relationship. I guess it’s fine if you want to flatten the data like this but you need to do something about the unique identifier since it is only for BodyALLDoc and you also need to include something from aLLDocumento. Or create a second entity for the documents

Comment: Can you give me an example? , it's better create a new entity to the documents or modify my entity in coredata?

Comment: I can’t tell you which one is better because I don’t know your app and what the data is used for but in general I would say it’s better to have a second entity with a one-to-many relationship